# Importing large XML File into MSSQLExpress through Powerhsell

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, sqlbulkcopy

as the title sugests i have to import large (6GB) XML files into an SQLExpress server. Since this has to happen on a daily basis on the VServer itself and im not allowed to install more Software i'm limited to powershell (although upgraded to Version 4).
My source of inspiration has been [Use PowerShell to Load XML Data into SQL Server](http://sqlmag.com/powershell/use-powershell-load-xml-data-sql-server)

My current script looks like this:

```
#database variables
$serverInstance="QLIKVIEWSQL\QLIKV_SQLEXPRESS";
$database = "Xml-Import_TEST"; 
$table = "dbo.vkjournal";

#opening the sql connection
$cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$user="user";
$password="password"
$cn.ConnectionString="Server=$serverInstance;Database=$database;user   Id=$user;password=$password;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
$cn.Open();


#Semi-automatic creation of the XmlSchema
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM "+$table+" WHERE 1 = 2";
$cmd.Connection = $cn
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da.Fill($ds, $table) | Out-Null
$ds.WriteXmlSchema('C:\Users\qlikview\Desktop\SQLTEST\'+$table+'.xsd');


#Reading the xml-schema and loading bw1.xml into an DataSet object. Then bulkcopying to sql.
$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet"
$ds.ReadXmlSchema("C:\Users\qlikview\Desktop\SQLTEST\dbo.vkjournal.xsd");
$ds.ReadXml("C:\Users\qlikview\Desktop\SQLTEST\bw1.xml")
$dtProd = $ds.Tables[0]
$bc = new-object ("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $cn
$bc.DestinationTableName = $table;
$bc.WriteToServer($dtProd)

$cn.Close()
```

As usual powershell doesnt throw any errors, just the words IgnoreSchema (if i comment out the ReadXmlSchema line) or InferSchema (if i dont) and nothing happens on the SQLServer side.

The created XMLSchema(shortened) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="dbo.vkjournal">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="KASS_NR" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="VKJO_DATUM" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="VKJO_ZEIT" type="xs:duration" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="VKJO_BESTE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And although i have tried to change some element names as suggested in [1](http://sqlmag.com/powershell/use-powershell-load-xml-data-sql-server) the results havent changed.

I would be very grateful for some hints, thanks.

Comment: One thing that concerns me Express version size limit is 10GB, 2x load and you are done.

Comment: 6GB of XML is maybe (guess, probably even less) 1GB of SQLdata, and the data are getting Overwritten. After the Import works, i hav a good explanation why we need a full version or why to install MySQL.

Comment: Why Powershell, use T-SQL directly, `DECLARE @messagebody XML;     SELECT @messagebody = BulkColumn
                              FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Work\Products1000.XML', SINGLE_CLOB) AS X; INSERT INTO table(xml_column) SELECT @messagebody`

Comment: Honestly because my Powershell is better than my T-SQL :) I tried your propose and got an *Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition* error. My guess is that the xml values and the table values are different?

Comment: Do you store XML File itself in database or do you want to parse XML and put values from XML in tables in database?

Comment: Put the values from XML in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the Question was somehow not popular, i found a working method using [this microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806(v=sql.120).aspx). The full script throw some errors so i ditched the validation and copied only the bulk load. I had to install [msxml 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6276) and i did install SQLXML 4.0 if thats important.
For those who have big table definitions like i did, the script above (see section #Semi-automatic creation of the XmlSchema) helps tremendously reducing the needed hand writting.

```
set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload.4.0")
objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS_INSTANCE;database=YOURDB;integrated security=SSPI"
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "C:\error.log"

' Check constraints and initiate transaction (if needed)
   ' objBL.CheckConstraints = True
   ' objBL.Transaction=True
  'Execute XML bulkload using file.
  objBL.Execute "C:\XSDfile.xml", "C:\File.xml"
  set objBL=Nothing
```